# Timeseries DB with nice java query client

Tags: java, database, time-series, dsl, grafana

I'm looking for any type of timeseries db for storing stock market data. Actually solutions like Grafana, Prometheus, InfluxDB are almost fit. But in addition to web ui with charts and dashboards, I need nice java client to be able to query datapoints. And I can't find any appropriate one.

It would be great to see some kind of DSL with aggregation functions:

```
Metric myStockData = db.getMetric("exhangeRate");
Set<Datapoints> daysAverages = myStockData
    .groupBy(Grouping.Days)
    .average()
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, if someone is interested, I preferred InfluxDB for my solution. It can be easily triggered via some kind of SQL